# Cant build HQL query that tie entites that relates via 'contained in element collection relation'

Tags: hibernate, components, hql

I have following classes/mappings in my model:

```
@Entity
public class UpSaleReason {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Subject subject;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Reason> relatesToRegisteredReasons;
}

@Embeddable
public class Reason {
    @ManyToOne
    private Subject subject;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Category category;
}

@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}


@Entity
public class ConversationCase {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Reason reason;
}
```

and trying to execute that HQL:

```
select r from UpSaleReason as r, ConversationCase as cc
where cc.reason in elements(relatedReasons) and cc.id = :id
```

which gives me:

> ... Caused by: java.sql.SQLException:
>   Single column select required in IN predicate in statement [select
>   upsalereas0_.id as id8_, upsalereas0_.subject_id as subject2_8_
>   from UpSaleReason upsalereas0_ cross join ConversationCase conversati1_
>   where (conversati1_.subject_id in (select relatestor2_.category,
>   relatestor2_.subject_id from up_sale_to_registered_reasons
>   relatestor2_ where upsalereas0_.id=relatestor2_.UpSaleReason_id))
>   and conversati1_.id=?]

What should I do to tie two entites in HQL that relates to each other via relation that could be described as 'component propery value of one entity should be contained in ElementCollection of other'?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `in elements(relatedReasons)`, which is generating an inner select statement for the full reason object, with both category and subject.

It looks like it should be `elements(relatedReasons.subject)`

Comment: Sorry, I gave wrong HQL. I need that select:

select r from UpSaleReason as r, ConversationCase as cc
where cc.reason in elements(relatedReasons) and cc.id = :id

Comment: I.e. I need compare by full Reason (subject AND category)

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to be able to use elements() with a compound key like that. Is there a specific reason you chose to not have an id on the Reason? That would simplify these sorts of queries.

Comment: Reason is component so it has not id